# Values in mysql resetting back to 0 after update query

Tags: mysql

this is what my table looks like

```
_____________________________________________________________
|  id  |  val1  |  val2  |  val3  |  val4  |  val5  |  val6  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|   1  |  1300  |  1300  |     0  |  2000  |  1300  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|  10  |     0  |     0  |     0  |  2000  |     0  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
```

Now I update

```
UPDATE points set val5 = CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN val5 + 500 WHEN id = 1 THEN val5 + 500 END WHERE id IN ('10','1')
```

This is what my table looks like

```
_____________________________________________________________
|  id  |  val1  |  val2  |  val3  |  val4  |  val5  |  val6  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|   1  |  1800  |  1800  |     0  |  2000  |  1800  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|  10  |   500  |   500  |     0  |  2000  |   500  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
| 157  |     0  |     0  |     0  |   800  |     0  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
```

Now I update again **(this is where it's broken)**

```
UPDATE points set val5 = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN val5 + 500 END, val6 = CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN val6 + 500 END WHERE id IN ('10','1')
```

My table looks like this

```
_____________________________________________________________
|  id  |  val1  |  val2  |  val3  |  val4  |  val5  |  val6  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|   1  |  2300  |  2300  |     0  |  2000  |  2300  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|  10  |  1000  |     0  |   500  |  2000  |     0  |   500  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
| 157  |     0  |     0  |     0  |   800  |     0  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
| 158  |     0  |     0  |     0  |   800  |     0  |     0  |
|______|________|________|________|________|________|________|
```

Did you notice how val2 and val5 went back to zero even though I didn't tell it to? what am I missing?

Comment: Is `id` a string or number?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I fail to see how your updates would keep adding rows as your example shows.

Comment: that part is another query before the query I am displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an expression does not match any of the `when` clauses in a `case`, it returns `null`, which is not the behavior you seem to want. Instead, you should return the column itself in an `else` clause:

```
UPDATE points 
SET    val5 = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN val5 + 500 ELSE val5 END, -- Notice the else
       val6 = CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN val6 + 500 ELSE val6 END -- Here too
WHERE  id IN (10, 1)
```

Comment: **@Mureinik**, in your CASE statement you have `id` as a number.  In your WHERE statement you have it as a varchar.  Which is it?

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 1):

For the first query you don't even need a CASE statement.  The following should work:

```
UPDATE points 
SET val5 = val5 + 500
WHERE id IN (10, 1)
```

For the second query you will have to have the ELSE statement:

```
UPDATE points 
SET val5 = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN val5 + 500 ELSE val5 END, 
    val6 = CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN val6 + 500 ELSE val6 END 
WHERE id IN (10, 1)
```

I noticed one other thing.  You are using `id = 1` and `id = 10` in your CASE statement.  But then you use `id IN ('10','1')` in your WHERE statement.  So, is `id` a string or number.  In my examples above I changed it to a number.